# Database with low memory requirements and Ruby interface

Tags: ruby, database, nosql, memory-management, key-value-store

I need a database with low memory requirements for a small virtual server with few memory. At the moment I'm stuck with SQLite and Kyoto Cabinet or Tokyo Cabinet. The database should have a Ruby interface.

Ideally I want to avoid key-value-stores, because I have “complex” queries (more complex than looking up a single key) and tuples as keys. On the other hand I don't want to have a fixed schema and avoid the planning and migration efforts of a SQL database. A database server is also not necessary because only a single application will use the database.

Do you have any recommendations and numbers for me?

Comment: How much memory can you allow the server to consume?

Comment: I would say less than 10 MiB. But I could upgrade the server if there's a convincing feature of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a great fit for what you are trying to do. It's used by a lot of [companies](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) as their embedded app database because it's flexible, fast, well tested, and has a small footprint. It's easy to create and blow away tables so it plays well with testing or single-application-use data stores.

The SQL language it uses is rich enough to do normal things but I'd recommend  using [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) with it. It's a great ORM and easily lets you treat it as a full-blown ORM, or drop all the way down to talking raw SQL to the DBM.

Comment: SQLite is somewhat limited (http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html). I would really like to be able write to views. Moreover, the missing DROP COLUMN support seems problematic for migrations to me (you could do the migration by creating a temporary table, copying the data except for the columns to be dropped, drop the original table and recreate from the temporary table, but that's really ugly).

Answer (score 3):

1. There is [schema-less Postgresql](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2012/03/json_in_postgres.html) (Postgresql 9.2 + json). Not as hard/confusing to set up as I thought. You get lots of flexibility with queries while still getting the benefits of schema-less storage.  PG 9.2 includes plv8js, a new language handler that allows you to create functions in JavaScript. Here is one example of how you can index and query JSON docs in PG 9.2: http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/249-Using-PLV8-to-index-JSON.html
2. CouchDB (Use BigCouch. Based on CouchDB, but fewer bugs/problems.):

   - very low memory requirements.
   - schema-less.
   - HTTP-based interface. Ruby has plenty of HTTP clients. HTTP caching (like Varnish) can also speed reads.
   - creative/complex queries. You can create indexes and queries on any key in the document (record). You can get very creative with queries since the indexes are very programmable.

   Downsides:

   - Learning curve of setting up your queries/indexes.
   - You have to schedule a type of cleanup operation called "compaction".
   - Data will take up more space compared to other databases.
   - More: http://www.paperplanes.de/2010/7/26/10_annoying_things_about_couchdb.html

   If disk is cheap and memory expensive, it would make a good candidate for your needs.

   "...another strength of CouchDB, which has proven to serve thousands of concurrent requests only needed about 10MB of RAM - how awesome is that?!?!" (From: http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/03/hbase-vs-couchdb-in-berlin.html )

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution that only has a database file and no running server, probably. In that case, Sqlite should be a good choice - If you don't need it, just close the connection and that's it. Sqlite has everything that you need from and RDMS (expect for enforcing FK's directly, but that can be done with triggers), with a very little memory footprint, so in that case you are probably worried more about the memory your ORM (if any) uses.

Personally, I use sqlite for that use case as well, as it is portable and easy to access and install (which shouldn't be the problem on a server anyway, but in a desktop application it is).

Comment: But with SQL you have the problem of schemas and the planning (drawing data model diagrams, converting them into normal form, etc.) overhead and maybe problems with schema migrations. SQLite would be my choice if I find no other solution, because I know that it will work.

It has been a while since I used ORMs (at last ActiveRecord). I got the impression that they only provide the lowest common denominator of the databases they abstract and generate sub optimal queries. But since SQLite only implements SQL 92 it shouldn't be a huge limitation.

Comment: @ott "problem of schemas and the planning (drawing data model diagrams, converting them into normal form, etc.) overhead and maybe problems with schema migrations" Why? It can be that complicated if you want to make it that way, or you could write some migrations for ActiveRecord or Sequel, and let them do the heavy lifting. Change the database adapter to MySQL, Postgres or something else, and the ORM will handle all the schema creation and manipulation still.

Comment: @ott As far as SQL query quality, I've looked at the output of ActiveRecord and Sequel many times and they're generating queries that are what I'd write most of the time. You'd be surprised how smart they are. And, if you see them going the wrong route, you can easily substitute your own hand-tweaked SQL and they'll happily use it. They sure beat using DBI and writing everything by hand.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Sequel looks promising, because you have greater control and the actual SQL database isn't abstracted if you want to. If I'll use a SQL database, I'll probably try Sequel.

Answer (score 0):

BerkeleyDB with SQLite API is what you need.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/sql-160887.html

Comment: What are the advantages of Berkeley DB over SQLite's default storage engine in practice?

Comment: @ott SQLite's default storage engine uses database-level locking, which means only one writer can access to the database at a time. BerkeleyDB uses page-level locking and MVCC, so it permits more than one concurrent writers. If your application is concurrent write-intensive, you should use BerkeleyDB storage engine. If your application doesn't modify the data frequently, SQLite's default storage engine and BerkeleyDB perform same.